# why use of unassigned local variable. C#. create a new node

Tags: c#, unassigned-variable

I have a problem with the following code. I need to only create a new pcba node if it is different from the one created previously. I need to work with the same variable if that variable not change.

```
foreach (XmlNode node in dc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
            {
                PCBA pcb = null;

                if (serialPCB != node.Attributes["PCBpos"].Value.ToString())
                    pcb = new PCBA();

                pcb.PCBA_Status = status;
                long number = 0;
                bool validation = false;
                if (node.Attributes != null && node.Attributes["PCBpos"] != null)
                  {
                    validation = long.TryParse(node.Attributes["PCBpos"].Value, out number);
                  }
                 //bool validation = long.TryParse(node.Attributes["PCBpos"].Value, out number);
                if (validation == true)
                {
                    pcb.PCBA_POSITION = node.Attributes["PCBpos"].Value.ToString();
                    serialPCB = node.Attributes["PCBpos"].Value.ToString();

                    if (status != "PASS")
                    {
                        List<Group> groups = new List<Group>();
                        Group group = new Group();

                        group.Group_Name = node.Attributes["COMP_NAME"].Value.ToString();
                        group.Group_Status = status;
                        group.Group_FailureCode = node.Attributes["FaultName"].Value.ToString();

                        List<Measurement> measurements = new List<Measurement>();
                        Measurement measurement = new Measurement();
                        measurement.Measurement_Name = node.Attributes["COMP_NAME"].Value.ToString();
                        measurement.Measurement_Status = status;
                        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(dc.DocumentElement.Attributes["LOCATION"].Value.ToString());
                        var ruta = di.GetFiles(node.Attributes["COMP_NUMBER"].Value.ToString() + "-*");
                        if (ruta.Length > 0)
                            measurement.Measurement_ImagePath = di + "\\" + ruta[0].ToString();
                        measurements.Add(measurement);
                        group.Measurements = measurements;
                        groups.Add(group);
                        pcb.Groups = groups;
                    }

                    pcbas.Add(pcb);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Where are `serialPCB` and `node` assigned?  Obviously, you need to show us all the relevant code.

Comment: "I need to work with the same variable if that variable not change." Which variable? It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: assign it `null` when declaring as it is local variable, `PCBA pcb = null;`

Comment: can't you just assign `PCBA pcb = serialPCB;` then if your if statement is true it will just create a new one instead

Comment: sorry, it is de complete code.

Answer (score 5):

For every `if` there's an `else`.

In your case `pcb` is not assigned if the condition is false.

Set it first to null. then before using it again check if it's still null.